# How Do I Write Text to a Google Doc using Drive API's Ruby Client?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-drive-api, google-api-client

Hello SO Ruby/Rails/Google community!

I'm looking for the correct way of making changes to the body of a Google Doc stored in Google Drive using Drive API Ruby Client.

Let's say I've required `'google/api_client'`, have an authorized client and drive instance, and have a starting template written in HTML.

I have no trouble creating fresh templates and multipart-uploading them to drive using

`@drive.files.insert`

to join file metadata:

```
@file = @drive.files.insert.request_schema.new({
            'title' => "#{Time.now.strftime('%m_%d_%Y_')}EOD",
            'description' => "The End of Day Log for #{Time.now.strftime('%m_%d_%Y')}",
            'mimeType' => 'text/html',
            'parents' => [{'id' => folder_id}]
        })
```

and the html template represented by:

`@media = Google::APIClient::UploadIO.new('eod_template.html', 'text/html')`

Having successfully uploaded the base template to Drive and capturing its file_id, I would like users to be able to append text entries to the base template using a form on my Rails site.

Given the existence of a micropost model and form, I suspect I'll be writing a method that get called on save that appends the submitted text to the Google Doc Template but I can't find how to do this in any of the Drive API documentation.

I'm looking for functionality identical to the apps-script `appendText(text)` method found at
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text

Anyone have any clever solutions? Documentation I should read? The Perfect Gem?

Thanks a mil for your time!

-B

Comment: Thanks for helping me edit, Kirill!

Answer (score 0):

I gather from the deafening silence that such a thing is not (easily) possible.
Bummer!
Not to be deterred, I implemented the following workaround - hope it works for you, future readers.
Instead of writing posts to a document dynamically, I let a day's worth of posts pool in my app until the end of day, at which point I write all posts to the Google Doc at once with Nokogiri. It's not great, but with some front-end trickery whereby I simulate the feel of a Google Doc, it's good enough.

Comment: I'll leave this thread open in case someone has a real answer (or one is created in the future...)